Getting java.io.IOException: NSS initialization failed error
Right now I am using the Keyclock version 21 and suddenly getting below error in my container app. I am using the azure container app.
Error:
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401585111Z  at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.configure(SunPKCS11.java:153)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401590821Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:257)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401596111Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:248)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401601081Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401606160Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:248)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401620226Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:226)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401625636Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(ProviderList.java:317)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401630746Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(ProviderList.java:334)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401635655Z  at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Providers.java:186)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401640694Z  at java.base/java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:537)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401645864Z  at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.ProviderList.<init>(ProviderList.java:128)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401655602Z  at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.<init>(GSSManagerImpl.java:56)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401660852Z  at java.security.jgss/org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager.getInstance(GSSManager.java:152)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401708380Z  at org.keycloak.common.util.KerberosJdkProvider.isKerberosAvailable(KerberosJdkProvider.java:68)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401773111Z  at org.keycloak.common.Profile$Feature.<clinit>(Profile.java:84)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.401811081Z  ... 23 more
2024-08-29T09:07:41.402025179Z Caused by: java.io.IOException: NSS initialization failed
2024-08-29T09:07:41.402033675Z  at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.Secmod.initialize(Secmod.java:243)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.402078198Z  at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:279)
2024-08-29T09:07:41.402084589Z  ... 41 more

Could anyone has idea on it?
Tried with updating the version of java and keyclock but getting same error.
